# I've created a Material Design elementary Wallpapers app. Where can I submit it?

Tags: wallpaper, android

Cassidy James Blaede mentioned in a [Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/+CassidyJames/posts/54pqPYgdjoZ) that he wanted to redesign the [current elementary Wallpapers app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.echo.elementaryoswallpaper) with Material Design and Freya wallpapers:

> Now we need to get this sucker updated with Freya wallpapers... and update it to the latest Android design guidelines. It's pretty old. xD﻿

So I took on the task as an exercise, and created such application from scratch:

[image: Elementary Wallpapers]

And I'm pretty happy with the results, since the new application even uses less RAM memory than the old one, and uses asynchronous image loading etc.
In fact, I'm so happy with it that I want it to become the new official app. However, I'm unsure on how (and where) to report this, since this is not really a bug, nor a feature-request. How can I get this out in the open?